# Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

```
import random
import pandas as pd

heart_rate = [random.randrange(45,125) for _ in range(500)]
blood_pressure_systolic = [random.randrange(140,230) for _ in range(500)]
blood_pressure_dyastolic = [random.randrange(90,140) for _ in range(500)]
temperature = [random.randrange(34,42) for _ in range(500)]
respiratory_rate = [random.randrange(8,35) for _ in range(500)]
pulse_oximetry = [random.randrange(95,100) for _ in range(500)]


vitalsign = {'heart rate' : heart_rate,
             'systolic blood pressure' : blood_pressure_systolic,
             'dyastolic blood pressure' : blood_pressure_dyastolic,
             'temperature' : temperature,
             'respiratory rate' : respiratory_rate,
             'pulse oximetry' : pulse_oximetry}


df = pd.DataFrame(vitalsign)


df.to_csv('vitalsign.csv')


mask = (50  < df['heart rate'] < 101 &
        140 < df['systolic blood pressure'] < 160 &
        90  < df['dyastolic blood pressure'] < 100 &
        35  < df['temperature'] < 39 &
        11  < df['respiratory rate'] < 19 &
        95  < df['pulse oximetry'] < 100
        , "excellent", "critical")

df.loc[mask, "class"]
```

it seems to be that,

error that i am  receiving :

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

. how can i sort it out

Comment: What line of the code is causing that error? The issue has to do with comparing something like a dictionary or list with something that is a string, char, int, etc. since these values cannot be compared.

Comment: You can't use `a < b < c` chained comparisons with pandas, for the same reason you have to use `&` instead of `and`.

Comment: @cs95 The indicated dupliciate is only a partial duplicate. since the duplicate does *not* use chained comparisons. There are two issues in the above code, and the duplicate only answers one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As user2357112 mentioned in the comments, you cannot use chained comparisons here. For elementwise comparison you need to use `&`. That also requires using parentheses so that `&` wouldn't take precedence.

It would go something like this:

```
mask = ((50  < df['heart rate']) & (101 > df['heart rate']) & (140 < df['systolic...
```

In order to avoid that, you can build series for lower and upper limits:

```
low_limit = pd.Series([90, 50, 95, 11, 140, 35], index=df.columns)
high_limit = pd.Series([160, 101, 100, 19, 160, 39], index=df.columns)
```

Now you can slice it as follows:

```
mask = ((df < high_limit) & (df > low_limit)).all(axis=1)
df[mask]
Out: 
     dyastolic blood pressure  heart rate  pulse oximetry  respiratory rate  \
17                        136          62              97                15   
69                        110          85              96                18   
72                        105          85              97                16   
161                       126          57              99                16   
286                       127          84              99                12   
435                        92          67              96                13   
499                       110          66              97                15   

     systolic blood pressure  temperature  
17                       141           37  
69                       155           38  
72                       154           36  
161                      153           36  
286                      156           37  
435                      155           36  
499                      149           36
```

And for assignment you can use np.where:

```
df['class'] = np.where(mask, 'excellent', 'critical')
```

Comment: just to let you know the first solution did not work but the second solution indeed solves my problem. thanks a lot and good luck helping others like me.

Comment: @ShamsulMasum If you add `, "excellent", "critical")` to the end like you did in the question, it won't work. It should only contain conditions. Then you can use np.where.

Comment: what if i need to add more class option, such as here i have only two (excellent and critical).

Comment: Can you post an example for that?

Answer (score -1):

solution is easy:

replace

```
 mask = (50  < df['heart rate'] < 101 &
            140 < df['systolic blood pressure'] < 160 &
            90  < df['dyastolic blood pressure'] < 100 &
            35  < df['temperature'] < 39 &
            11  < df['respiratory rate'] < 19 &
            95  < df['pulse oximetry'] < 100
            , "excellent", "critical")
```

by

```
mask = ((50  < df['heart rate'] < 101) &
        (140 < df['systolic blood pressure'] < 160) &
        (90  < df['dyastolic blood pressure'] < 100) &
        (35  < df['temperature'] < 39) &
        (11  < df['respiratory rate'] < 19) &
        (95  < df['pulse oximetry'] < 100)
        , "excellent", "critical")
```