# Problem with Error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a code to define buildings geometric shape, but I have this error message:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I read a lot of posts about it here and somewhere online, but I couldn't find anything similar.

This is my csv_file:

```
fid Shrt_axis   Lng_axis    angle   area_rett   perimeter   area
1   12.5    26.07   136.31  325.91  77.15   299.28
2   11.01   11.68   105.24  128.66  45.39   125.11
```

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
Tabella = pd.read_csv("prova_2.csv", sep=";", header= )

lato_corto = Tabella.loc[:,'Shrt_axis']    
lato_lungo = Tabella.loc[:,'Lng_axis']
#continue with other dates from my data set.

rapporto_lati = lato_lungo / lato_corto

for row in Tabella:
    if 1 =< rapporto_lati =< 1.1:
        print("è un quadrato")
```

Then i read something on internet, but it didn't work correctly:

```
if (rapporto_lati > 1) & (rapporto_lati < 1.1):
    print('è un quadrato')
```

In this case, I hadn't any error message, but the result wasn't ok.

Comment: The best duplicate I have found so far is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834028/use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-or-a-all?rq=1 . Unfortunately, this is flagged itself as a duplicate, but the latter only partially solves the problem (it doesn't handle chained comparisons, while the question linked in this comment does). Hence, I'm loath to mark this question as a duplicate yet.

Comment: The last two lines of code should also yield an error; the same error, in fact.

Comment: Note that if you're stepping through your dataframe row-wise, you should do things differently. But, in fact, you shouldn't be stepping through your dataframe row-wise: you need to operate on the whole table/column/series at once.

Comment: @00 the last two lines of code do not yield an error, because `&` is a valid operation on numpy boolean arrays. At least in my version it looks equivalent to [np.logical_and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). The condition is then equivalent to something like `if np.array([True, True, False, False,...]):` which always is `True` as long as the array is not empty.

Comment: @Leporello For which version of Python and NumPy? If I copy your code, I get a `ValueError`, as above. I'm using Python 3.7.3 with NumPy 1.16.4. Perhaps this has long been a warning, and has been upgraded to an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.  I use Python 3.6 and NumPy included in this version. I tried to use the & and | instead "and" "or", but how I said in my first post, it doesn't work, i didn't have the result expected. I need to be sure about the code, because this is only an example, but the whole table has 12500 rows.

Comment: @00 Python 2.7.15 and numpy 1.14.3 here: `np.array([True, True]) & np.array([False, True])` is a valid operation returning `np.array([False, True])` and does not give any warning. FWIW I think making it an error is better design (because of the ambiguities such as that of the OP).

Comment: @Leporello Indeed, I wouldn't rely on this behaviour, even if it's possible. While it definitely works for lists (any non-empty list, even `[0]` or `[False]`, evaluates as `True`), NumPy arrays are quite different beasts.

Comment: @Leporello This is odd: I'm running your example with Python 2.7.16 and NumPy 1.14.3 (on MacOS), and I do get a `ValueError` with `if np.array([True, True]) & np.array([False, True]): pass`. Something's fishy here.

Comment: @00 I'm on Windows 10 using an Anaconda distribution (conda 4.6.14). The thing actually makes [bitwise and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html?highlight=#numpy.bitwise_and) rather than logical and (tested with the bitwise doc examples). Maybe it is an implementation quirk?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if ((rapporto_lati > 1) & (rapporto_lati < 1.1)).all():
    print("è un quadrato")
```

You can only use the (chained) comparison method if the variable concerns a single item: for multiple items, such as a list, (NumPy) array or Pandas Series, you'll need to ascertain the comparison *for every individual element*. This is why you need `.all()` (or `.any()`, if your intention is that just one item-comparison being valid is enough).

For the *chained* comparison, you still *can't* do the following with arrays and such:

```
(1 <= rapporto_lati < 1.1).all()   # invalid
```

For NumPy arrays (and thus Pandas Series), you have to perform the comparisons individually, and combine the comparisons. Each comparison yields an array with `True` or `False` items, and these two arrays can be combined with the `&` operator (using standard boolean logic). You will need to wrap the two comparisons in parentheses as well, since the `&` operators binds tighter than the comparison operators.

With all that, you arrive at the above construction.