# if else condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

when I running following code

```
from datetime import datetime

if ((dfyz['year_x'] < datetime.now().year) or ((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) and (dfyz['mon'] < datetime.now().month))):
     dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct']
elif (((dfyz['year_x'] == datetime.now().year) and (dfyz['mon'] >= datetime.now().month)) or ((dfyz['year_x'] > datetime.now().year))):
       dfyz['pred_n'] = dfyz['yhat']*dfyz['pct_ft']
```

i am getting following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help me in fixing it, i have tried replacing and with & and or with | as well but still get same error

Comment: What is in `dfyz`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `if` statement. You have a Pandas(?) column which contains multiple Boolean values (e.g., `[True, True, False]`), for which no boolean value is assigned. Would you want it to be treated as `True`, because it's not empty? Or `True` because it contains `True`? Or `False` because it contains `False`? Pandas (or whatever) does not make that decision: you have to be explicit and use one of the methods suggested to *produce* a single Boolean value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834028/use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-or-a-all)